# Proof by contradiction not contradicting

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If the proof by contradiction never contradicts that means that the original statement is false right? Or is this way of thinking flawed?

Comment: If you can't find a contradiction, it doesn't necessarily mean anything.

Comment: okay, thanks!!!

Comment: Let's try to prove there is no life on Alpha Centauri.  So assume there is.  Go through 2000 years of history.  Nothing seems to contradict.  So it must be there is?

Answer (score 2):

There can be three reasons for not being able to find a contradiction.

1. The original statement is indeed false, so when you assumed the contrary, you assumed something that is true, and so there is no contradiction, and hence you couldn't find a contradiction.
2. The original statement is true, so when you assumed the contrary, you assume something that is false, but the theory within which you are working is not complete and in fact not powerful enough to generate a contradiction.
3. The original statement is true, so when you assumed the contrary, you assumed something that is false, but *you* were unable to generate a contradiction even though the theory you are working with is powerful enough to generate that contradiction.

So, as you can see, there are several explanations for not being able to find a contradiction, and in some of those the statement is false, and in others the statement is true. Therefore, you cannot infer the statement is false just because you cannot derive a contradiction.

Comment: If you can find something more incisive to say about this Question, please expand your Answer.  Otherwise this only amounts to a Comment already made by Doug M.

Comment: @hardmath Ok, how about now?

Comment: Yes, good enough!  I suspect that a scenario could be constructed to *validate* the OP's intuition, that under some circumstances a failure to obtain a contradiction is a justification for concluding the original hypothesis is not true.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah, I figured scenario 1 would cover that option.  Anyway, thanks for pressing me into a better answer!

Answer (score 1):

A contradiction implies that the original statement is false but not being able to obtain one doesn't say anything about the statement.